# Zend clearparams() and setParams(array()) not working

Tags: php, zend-framework

Zend Framework Version : 1.12.3

I want to clear current request parameters and set new parameters in `_forward()` function.

I tried following both functions in controller but it doesn't clear the parameters

```
$this->getRequest()->setParams(array());   
$this->getRequest()->clearParams();
```

Found related issue : [ZF Issue 4026](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-4026)

But I can't get how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Params set via `GET` or `POST` are not saved in params list. They are read every time from PHP's `_GET` and `_POST` tables. To disable this you can set your own param sources by calling: `$this->getRequest()->setParamSources()`. This can be empty array (for not reading from other sources), or contain one or more of '_GET' or '_POST'.

Or you can just overwrite `_GET` or `_POST` tables.